# How can you redirect a user on page load and still have Twitter cards work

Tags: twitter, http-headers

I am integrating [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards) into my website, specifically the app install and deep linking feature. To do this, I added the required meta tags into the header section of my html page.

The feature in my app that posts to Twitter shares articles from other websites. In order to share a website url that is not on my domain but still have the twitter card show up, I made a simple short url that gets posted on Twitter that points to my html page with the meta tags and then redirects the user to the original site, but I am not getting the desired results.

**First**, I tried redirecting the user by returning a 301 response code in the headers. This redirects the user exactly as I want (keeps my redirect page out of the browser history), but the meta tags don't get picked up by Twitter so the card doesn't show up.

**Next**, I tried using a meta tag below the Twitter card meta tags like this:

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.mywebsite.com">
```

With this method the Twitter card shows up properly, but now the back button is enabled in the browser. Also, I read that this method is not advised because search engines tend to remove sites that do this from there results due to security reasons.

Does anyone know how to redirect the user without having the back button in the browser be enabled and still allow the meta tags to be evaluated? I would prefer a method of doing this without using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting way around this issue.

I only need the Twitter meta tags available when Twitter is the the one looking at my site. So, when a user or bot makes a request to my website (which Twitter has to do to populate the card information from the meta tags) I check the user agent that made the request. If it was a Twitter bot (its user agent is currently Twitterbot/1.0) then I return the page with a 200 response code in my header and a meta tag redirect (just in case). Otherwise, I return with a 302 response code and the browser redirects my use there immediately.

This gets around the back button issue and the issue of the search engines not liking my site with the meta tag redirects (since there bots will never see them!).

UPDATE

I recently had someone ask for more details about how I did this, so I figured I would provide an example. I was using C# for my server, but the code is pretty simple to figure out if you are using a different language.

```
/// <summary>
/// Redirects a user to the location related to the given id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
public ActionResult Index(Int32 id)
{
    // Retrieve details about the short link id passed in
    using (DataEntities context = new DataEntities())
    {
        ShortLink shortLink = context.ShortLinks.Single(s => s.Id == id);

        // If the user agent is a twitter bot (currently Twitterbot/1.0), return the page with a meta redirect (just in case) so Twitter can still read the meta tags.
        if (Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower().Contains("twitterbot"))
        {
            TwitterCardModel model = new TwitterCardModel
            {
                Id = id,
                Site = "@YOUR_TWITTER_HANDLE",
                Title = shortLink.Title,
                Description = shortLink.Description,
                RedirectUrl = shortLink.FullUrl,
                ImageUrl = shortLink.ImageUrl
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        // Otherwise, redirect the user to the original page.
        Response.Redirect(shortLink.FullUrl, true);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If the request was from a twitter bot, this was the HTML I returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    @* Twitter cards *@
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Model.Site">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="@Model.Title" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="@Model.Description" />

    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ImageUrl))
    {
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="@Model.ImageUrl">
    }

    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="YOUR APP NAME"/>
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="YOUR APPLE APP ID"/>
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="YOUR DEEP LINK TO YOUR CONTENT IN YOUR APP"/>

    @* Handle page redirect to the full article *@
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=@Model.RedirectUrl">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing, but it doesn't seem to work on mobile for me. Have you tried it on mobile?

Comment: Both the twitter mobile app for iOS and mobile website have been working for me. What part isn't working for you?

Comment: If I click on the card link on twitter mobile web site it also has "Twitterbot/1.0" in user agent string, so I get the metapage instead of the redirect. Looks like twitter converts/proxies the links on the card to t.co/... and makes a request with Twitterbot user agent.

Comment: Nevermind. This was my mistake. I had varnish caching enabled. I just made requests uncachable. It works as expected.